# 2.5" SSD in a 3.5" desktop drive bay normal?

Tags: ssd, computer-building, case, adapter, drive-bay

I'm a little out of touch with modern desktop builds, but I recently built a new machine anyway. I want to pick up a SSD for my I/O intensive apps (EverQuest 2 and Flash CS4 mostly), but I'm having trouble finding any in the 3.5" form factor.

Is this expected, or do I fail at product search? And, if it is expected, do 2.5" SSDs come with an adapter to fit them in my desktop machine, or will I need to purchase one separately? And, finally, if I do need to purchase an adapter, are they pretty standard or are some better than others. General advice is most welcomed, though specific product recommendations in addition would be helpful!

Comment: Just mount it somewhere with double-sided tape. There are no moving parts, it might as well be dangling off a cable or sit on the bottom of the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just buy a 2.5" drive and use a mounting kit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now that they all use the same SATA ports, you just use the same standard connectors as any other hard drive.

Comment: +1 All I have seen are 2.5". I understood this was the form factor so the adapter is the way to go.

Comment: BTW the kit on a picture looks like 3.5" for 5.25" bay, not 2.5" for 3.5" bay

Comment: @RocketSurgeon - Good point +1, I can't find a better one though :( If you (or anyone) finds one, feel free to edit the picture

Comment: @snark - Thanks. second picture is great - I found the first one but thought it was a little dark/hard to tell... Anyway, uploading to tinypic so other sites don't get mad!

Answer (score 1):

Most SSDs tend to fit a 2.5" form factor, although there are some exceptions such as the [OCZ Colossus](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3608). Adapters/brackets/mounting kits can be bought from most online computer stores. A [Toshiba/Kingston SSD](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3747&p=7) is one of the few drives that comes with a 3.5" adapter, but I wouldn't recommend the drive in terms of [performance](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3747&p=10). I can't advise on the pros and cons of the different adaptors, as personally my SSD just "rests" in a 3.5" slot - there are no moving parts so I'm not that concerned about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ICY DOCK MB882SP-1S-1B 2.5" to 3.5" drive adapter.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817994064

Comment: I bought an X-25M not long ago and it came with its own 3.5" adapter kit in addition to the Icy Dock MB882SP-1S-1B I threw in my cart.  Oh well!  The Icy Dock was of much better quality than the metal angle brackets that shipped with the SSD!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can use any laptop hard drives in a desktop, provided they are new enough that they use the SATA interface. No adapters should be needed, and it should rest nicely in your A: drive, floppy drive port.

It will also save you a little bit of power. but at the expense of a bit of speed. However, the 3.5 inch ssd's tend to cost a little more to buy. So, to recap

2.5 pros

1. lower power consumption
2. will fit the desktop, but won't sit tight unless you get a bracket to hold it in place
3. lower price

3.5 pros

1. faster speed
2. will fit nicely and screw in place