# Can I use a 2.5" SSD in my desktop PC?

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2.5“ SSD in a 3.5” desktop drive bay normal?](https://superuser.com/questions/116226/2-5-ssd-in-a-3-5-desktop-drive-bay-normal)

I want to put to buy a 2.5" SSD to use in my desktop. May I know whether they are using the same types of power and data connection? Do I need to buy adaptor and a enclosure?

This is my motherboard

http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3598#ov

As I recall, my desktop uses a "L- shape" connector for the hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

The SATA connector on standard 2.5" drives is identical to what a 3.5" drive uses.

Depending on your exact chassis, you may need an adapter plate in order to properly mount the drive.  (Some SSDs come with one.)