# Cannot find the SSD slot for my Ostrog Enermax Case

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, case

For the life of me, I can not figure out where I am supposed to put my 2.5 in SSD in the Ostrog Enermax Case. The case has ssd support supposedly, but I have no idea where it is.

http://www.enermaxusa.com/downloads/datasheet_eca3253.pdf
http://www.enermaxusa.com/case_eca3253.php

This is my first time putting together a computer, so I was wondering if I could get some advice on how to mount my SSD card. What am I missing?

Comment: Most SSDs come with a bracket that allows them to fix in a standard 3.5 inch hard drive slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD's are 2.5" drive, and your chassis only has 5.25" and 3.5" drive bays.

You'll need a 2.5" -> 3.5" converter/carrier/brackets.  Many SSD's come with them already, but if yours didn't you can get them pretty easily from most computer stores.

Something like [this](http://ca.startech.com/HDD/Brackets/Adapter-Kit-to-Mount-25-HDD-in-35-Drive-Bay~BRACKET25), or [this](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817994085), etc.  There's many different makes/models.

[image]

For more info check out this SU question: [2.5" SSD in a 3.5" desktop drive bay normal?](https://superuser.com/questions/116226/2-5-ssd-in-a-3-5-desktop-drive-bay-normal)